# In a Java web app, how can I give the user a "session" after he/she logs in?

Tags: java, session, web-applications

After the user has entered name/password, I need to store some sort of session to give the user access to the web app features.

I have done something similar in PHP, but how can I achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Java servlet you automatically have session-stuff provided for your use.  So long as your servlet method is extending [HttpServlet](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), you will have access to [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), which will give you access to [HttpSession](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) -- which you can use to get/set session-stuff.

Something like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

      HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
      session.setAttribute( "myAttribute", "My Value");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this stored in cookies on the user side or server side?

Comment: What do you mean by 'this'???  You mean the class I cited above???  If so, that class is something YOU must write on the server side and deploy inside of a java servlet container such as Tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/).  If by 'this' you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: The attributes I mean. It'd be silly if I stored the user's ID and that he was logged in as a cookie, since a user could just modify them.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  Yeah, you don't want to store that in the cookie, you're right.  What you want to do is just store the user's username in the cookie but then on the server keep as association between the username and the user's logged-in status.

Comment: Interesting idea. But in that case, an attacker could simply change his username to a valid, logged in user. I think it might be easier to simply constrain access to the resources in question.

Comment: @samoz - Session data is stored on the server, just like with php. Session hijacking can be done by guessing/knowing the session id, this is also similar to php.

Comment: @Ishtar ahh ok, thanks for the clarification. After a little reading, I figured this out.

Comment: @samoz: It sounds like you have something that works for you; but, for clarification, along with storing the username in the cookie you would also want to couple that with some generated-value -- store both of those in the cookie as well as on your server, validate both of them on the server-side every time a request is made for a secured-resource.  As Ishtar hinted at, you could also just couple the session-id and some generated-value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
  // rest of the code
  HttpSession ses = req.getSession(true);
}
```

Check API for HttpSession class

Comment: The JSESSIONID, which identifies the Session is transported via cookie or via URL parameter.